# Can't break out of Python loop

Tags: python

I'm having problems breaking out of a loop in Python. It just won't break out.

Here is dl.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import urllib
import urllib2
import os
import sys
import re 
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

url = sys.argv[1]
limit = sys.argv[2]

count = 0

while True :
    if count >= limit :
        break
    print 1;
    count += 1

print 'Complete ... exiting';
```

It just loops forever, I can't understand why. Python is not my native language, I'm using it to code some shell scripts.

I run it like so `./dl.py http://url.com 3`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could be that `limit` is a string, try `count >= int(limit)` You could also change the `while` for a `for` loop.

Comment: @Cyber that's not how that works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert `limit` to an integer using `int(limit)`.  In Python 2.x `3 > '2'` will *always* return `False` so your loop never completes.

Comment: Your statement that `3 > '2"` is `False` is only accurate in Python 2. In Python 3, it's an error and will raise an exception.

Comment: And only guaranteed accurate in CPython 2. Generaly, in Python 2, "such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily" -- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Comment: @Blckknght - true statement - I've edited my answer to qualify it as being relevant to Python 2.x only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `limit` to an integer using `int(limit)` (else it will be treated as a string by Python when read from the command line). Integers are evaluated to be less than strings (at least in Python 2).

```
>>> int < str
True
```

Comment: Note that this issue will only exist (in this form) in Python 2. In Python 3, comparing unlike types is usually an error!

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks! I'll note that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sys.argv[2]` will return a string, and when you compare a string with an integer in Python, the string is always greater. Try using `if count >= int(limit):` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `sys.argv` just one time when you are many arg and use `int` for limit because the `sys.argv` get string from input :

```
 user_args = sys.argv[1:]
 url, limit = user_args
 limit=int(limit)
```